# Javascript appendChild() argument is not a function

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

```
var view = {
    displayTodos: function () {
        var todosUl = document.querySelector('ul');
        todosUl.innerHTML = '';
        todoList.todos.forEach(function(todo){
            var todoLi = document.createElement('li');
            var todoTextWithCompletion = ''
            if (todo.completed) {
                todoTextWithCompletion = '(X) ' + todo.todoText;
            }
            else {
                todoTextWithCompletion = '( ) ' + todo.todoText;
            }
            todoLi.textContent = todoTextWithCompletion;

            todoLi.appendChild(this.createDeleteButton());
            todosUl.appendChild(todoLi);
        });
    },
    createDeleteButton: function () {
        var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
        deleteButton.textContent = 'Delete';
        deleteButton.className = 'deleteButton';
        return deleteButton;
    }
};
```

I was trying to add a button to each item in my list but now whenever I run view.displayTodos() I get the error message: "TypeError: this.createDeleteButton is not a function"

I think the problem is related to the line: 
todoLi.appendChild(this.createDeleteButton());
but I am at a loss as to why it's not working.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: the context of `this` is not what you think it is.

Comment: Please include a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Like epascarello said, it looks like you are misunderstanding the scope of "this".

Comment: You are probably passing `view.displayTodos` as a function and losing `this`. For this example, simplest solution is to replace `this.createDeleteButton()` with `view.createDeleteButton()`

Comment: Where is `todoList` defined?

Comment: @TedWhitehead It's not the problem, the error happens after that line

Comment: @JuanMendes Totally, but would be good to have the full script. The issue is definitely `this` referring to the forEach() loop, not the parent object.

Comment: @TedWhitehead That's my point, it doesn't really matter, we pinpointed the problem already

Answer (score 1):

replacing `this.createDeleteButton()` with `view.createDeleteButton()` seems to work

Thanks Juan

Answer (score -1):

simplest way to solve is save `this` to `that`

```js
var view = {   
     displayTodos: function () {
       console.log("displayTodos",this);
       var arr=[1,2];
       var that=this;
      arr.forEach(function(todo){
   //   console.log("todolist",this);
         that.createDeleteButton();
        
       });
   },   
   createDeleteButton: function () {
      console.log("create");
     } 
   };
view.displayTodos();
```

second method::::  Pass the current object as the second parameter

```js
var view = {   
     displayTodos: function () {
       var arr=[1,2];
       
      arr.forEach(function(todo){
     
         this.createDeleteButton();
        
       },this);
   },   
   createDeleteButton: function () {
      console.log("create");
     } 
   };
view.displayTodos();
```